# Strange Google Maps Geocoding behavior -- doesn't match Google Maps location at all

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was trying to geocode UNC-Chapel Hill and got a very bizarre result.

Here is my JSON request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=University%20of%20North%20Carolina+Chapel%20Hill+North+Carolina&sensor=false
```

If you search that, you'll see that the result says it's in Chatham County, which is definitely incorrect. When I search for University of North Carolina on Google Maps, [it's correct](https://www.google.com/maps/place/University+of+North+Carolina+at+Chapel+Hill/@35.904912,-79.046913,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x89acc2d2cb17aaeb:0xb33bf0976497e0e0).

Any idea how to change my geocode request to improve the quality?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *it's correct*? I don't see any county specified in the address from Google Maps. So how can you tell it's correct? Anyway, it might be wrong. Is it possible that some parts of the University are in Chatham county? Check this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=University%20of%20North%20Carolina+Chapel%20Hill+orange+county,+North+Carolina&sensor=false

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more queries to your request

According to the docs 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering

You may be able to add route, locality, administrative_area, country,etc.
on your search query